# Mac pro (M1)macOS Monterey12.3 flutter run

Tags: macos, cocoapods

**Warning: CocoaPods not installed. Skipping pod install.
CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.**

in Terminal (Mac)

```
flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-arm, locale
    zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/lishuaihua/fvm/versions/2.2.3
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (9 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lishuaihua/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/lishuaihua/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at:
      /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_211.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.3, Build version 13E113
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone SE (3rd generation) (mobile) • 67357256-ED8B-4EBA-AD82-BCE0468F6430
      • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome
      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74
```

in Terminal (AndroidStudio)

```
flutter doctor --verbose
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 12.3 21E230 darwin-arm, locale zh-Hans-CN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/lishuaihua/fvm/versions/2.2.3
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (9 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/lishuaihua/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_211-b12)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 13.3, Build version 13E113
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install see https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#installation for instructions.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[!] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone SE (3rd generation) (mobile) • 67357256-ED8B-4EBA-AD82-BCE0468F6430 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 99.0.4844.74

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: I voted to close this question because no question is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your AndroidStudio to the lastest New Version

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

`$ sudo gem install cocoapods`

copy that and paste in terminal